# Oracle: Extract Graphical Database Representation

Tags: oracle, database-design

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Oracle Creating ER Diagrams and Data Dictionaries](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/973/oracle-creating-er-diagrams-and-data-dictionaries)

How can I extract a graphical (schema) representation of an Oracle database (tables and their relationships; with colums and datatypes....). Are there (free) tools, which can do this?

I think the Oracle SQL Developer has no such feature...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might try SQL Developer Data Modeller which does do graphical data models and is free - I don't know if it does reverse engineering though. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/datamodeler/sqldevdm31ea-download-515132.html

Comment: Thanks and welcome back :) Apparently [it does](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/973/oracle-creating-er-diagrams-and-data-dictionaries/980#980)...